# Windows XP (SP3) & IE8 cannot connect to (Exchange 2003) OWA

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, exchange-2003

Laptop running XP Pro (SP3) updated to IE8. When attempting to connect to OWA (Exchange 2003), IE8 states `"unable to display web page"`. This occurs prior to any sign-in screen. OWA site has been added to IE8's trusted sites list.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: Or can others on different computers? OWA on the server can break, so it is important to rule that out first.

Comment: OWA does indeed work for everyone else. The problem only appears with IE8 (haven't tested with IE9).